# Deleting rows from SQLite (Android) based on time

Tags: android, sqlite

I've seen some similar questions on here, but none of them are helping so I figured I see if I could get some personalized help. I'm adding things to my database with a column called 'time_added' which is in the form:

```
2011-12-20 09:55:28
```

I am then calling a method I wrote to delete based on time, currently I just want it to delete everything before now:

```
StringBuilder queryString = new StringBuilder("date('now') < date('");
queryString.append(KEY_TIME).append("')"); //.append("','+0 days')");
int c = mDatabase.delete(DATABASE_TABLE,  queryString.toString(), null)
```

So right now it prints a WHERE clause that says:

```
date('now') > date('time_added')
```

I thought this meant that everything that is before now will be deleted, but maybe I am wrong. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I remember having some trouble implementing this too. I don't remember why, but the date command didn't seem to cooperate. I just used a string comparison on the date format. Here's the code that I ended up using. It seems to work fine.

```
    // Range to cleanup anything in the DB that is older than 2 days
    //
    // NOTE: This value must be negative so that when it gets added to the
    // current date, it sets the range as anything older than 2 days ago
    int rangeInDays = -2;

    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

    Calendar range = Calendar.getInstance();
    range.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, rangeInDays);

    int numDeleted =
        mDatabase.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, "time_added" + " < '"
                    + dateFormat.format(range.getTime()) + "'", null);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would store your dates as integers using `getTimeInMilliseconds()`.  It makes comparisons easier and means you do not need to worry about international date formats.

Comment: While this idea is still correct, I think the other way looks neater because eventually I want to add days to the range, and that looks neater than all the math would, in my opinion. Thanks though!